# Generate Pivoted Pandas Dataframes by Changing 'Values' Argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have an empty list I want to populate with pivoted dataframes with the intention of looping over the list to generate heatmaps using seaborn.

The original dataframes look something like:

```
x   y   ds_ic       ele1    ele2    ele3        ele4
0   0   0.394888    18.8099 25.468  7.03E-15    0.417225
0   1   0.3990888   20.5525 23.54   0           0.331358
0   2   0.3901616   22.6762 19.5485 3.63E-11    0.448073
0   3   0.3838604   24.4072 27.781  0           0.406801
0   4   0.387536    21.6036 23.8371 0           0.263638
0   5   0.387536    23.4229 22.542  4.30E-14    0.395689
```

I'm using the following code to reshape the data and make it suitable for plotting:

```
def mapShape(dataframe_list):
    plotList = []
    for df in dataframe_list:
            df = df.pivot(index = 'y', columns = 'x', values = 'ds_ic')
            plotList.append(df)
    return plotList

shaped_dataframes = mapShape(simplified_dataframes)
```

Where `simplified_dataframes` is a list of dataframes that have the same shape as the original dataframe. This works fine for pivoting a single column of my choosing (i.e. whenever I manually set `values`).

The goal is to make a reshaped/pivoted dataframe for all columns *after* x-y. I thought of passing a column-header string to `values` of `df.pivot()`, resembling something like the following:

```
columns = ['ds_ic', 'ele1', 'ele2', 'ele3', 'ele4']
def mapShape(dataframe_list):
    plotList = []
    for df in dataframe_list:
        for c in columns:
            df = df.pivot(index = 'y', columns = 'x', values = c)
            plotList.append(df)
    return plotList

shaped_dataframes = mapShape(simplified_dataframes)
```

When I try this, `df.pivot()` throws a `KeyError` for `'y'`. I tried substituting  `df.pivot()` with `df.pivot_table()`, but that throws a `KeyError` for `'ele2'`. I have a feeling there is an easier way to do this and look forward to your suggestions. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your assigning the pivot_table back `df` in this line:`df = df.pivot(index = 'y', columns = 'x', values = c)`. In the next iteration, it will then try to pivot this pivot table, which doesn't have a `y`-colun. If you assign the pivot to `df2` and then append that to your plot list, it works like a charm :)

On another note; I don't know what and how and why you're plotting, but I feel there may be a more straightforward way. If you show your intended output, I could have  a look.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! My intended output is a list containing pivoted dataframes. I then iterate over this list, applying `seaborn.heatmap()` with each iteration, to generate the desired plots. I would go into greater detail, but then I would need to explain much more, and wind up having you do my job! The rest of my code functions well and I do get the plots I desire. Thanks again for the help.